# VIM comma is missing in insert mode

Tags: vim

I'm a VIM beginner, and I have a weird problem. I started using vim in a terminal emulator, but today I moved to gVim. Then I realized that I cannot write a comma in Insert mode! I tried `:map ,`, `:imap ,` both said no mapping found. THen I tried `:nomap ,` and `:inomap ,` both without any luck. As writing the commands, I am able to write the comma, but not in insert mode. What can be the problem?

---

Some details: I'm running a freshly installed ubuntu 9.04 system, with an english keyboard, but using a hungarian layout. I am able to write a comma in vim when writing into the "command line" of vim, after pressing : in command mode.

Comment: Do you have a `vimrc` file? This is `~/.vimrc` in UNIX, or `C:\Documents and Settings\(user name)\_vimrc` in Windows. This file might be configuring incorrect keymappings for GUI mode. Failing that, do you have an unusual keyboard layout?

Comment: Yes, I have a vimrc. There are no mappings in it (and `:map ,` would print it, wouldn't it?). And yes, I do have an unusual keyboard layout, it's a hungarian keyboard. That said, I still am able to write the comma into the "command line" (after hitting :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve it. Previously I used mkvimrc to generate my .vimrc. Now, I deleted it all, and created one manually. Not sure what caused it, but now it works as expected. Moral: don't be lazy, write your vimrc yourself. :)

Comment: I had similar problem and it looks that it was caused by enabled cindent in configuration.

Comment: The 'remove cindent' comment below solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 11):

remove the 'cindent' line from your .vimrc file. worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you type CTRL-V followed by a comma in insert mode? Do you get a comma?

Also, since you only have this problem in gvim and not vim, try running xev and typing , into it to see if the events look odd. (you may need to apt-get install x11-utils for xev) The events I get look like this:

```
KeyPress event, serial 30, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x236, subw 0x0, time 788140933, (138,120), root:(144,139),
    state 0x10, keycode 59 (keysym 0x2c, comma), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2c) ","
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2c) ","
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 30, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x236, subw 0x0, time 788141013, (138,120), root:(144,139),
    state 0x10, keycode 59 (keysym 0x2c, comma), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2c) ","
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: On this system, the problem exists with vim as well (I started learning vim on my old arch linux, which I recently changed to ubuntu, and started using gvim). This is my xev output: http://pastie.org/574928 It looks OK. Visual block mode and pressing comma doesn't work either.

Comment: CTRL-V in insert mode does a verbatim insert of the next character you type. CTRL-V goes into visual-block mode only if you were in normal (not insert) mode to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have something like this in your .vimrc `set cinkeys=0{,0},:,0#,!,!^F`? 
I run into this issue and solved it by removing the rogue exclamation mark 
 `set cinkeys=0{,0},:,0#,!^F`